# Bharat bringing sandals of Lord Rama

Tags: ramayana

It is said that Lord Rama moves to the forest with his empty feet without wearing any sandals. When Bharat went to forest to bring him back to Ayodhya but returns with Lord Rama's sandals (Paduka).

So my question where from the sandals came while Lord Rama didn't wear any sandals?

Comment: Where did you get that Lord Rama did not wear sandals?

Comment: Please watch this video it is Lord Rama himself says not to wear any sandals. https://youtu.be/F3F60d4SATk @commonman

Comment: Also Bharat knows about Lord Rama didn't wear any sandals https://youtu.be/sV7Tns7Xsgg  @commonman

Comment: Yes, seeming very strange!!

Comment: May be he took the sandals which Sri Rama used for few minitues on his request?

Comment: @UdayKrishna Thanks so much for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

It is ridiculous to use television serials as sources for Ramayana.

Rama was asked to take on the garb of a mendicant. A mendicant's footwear consists of two pieces of hardwood with a knob on each such that it can be held between the big toe and first toe.

Rama gave these to Bharatha such he could rule the kingdom as Rama's liege.

Comment: Yes, TV/Movies sources are not accepted here but in order to maintain quality of posts, wehttps://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/277) [mandate citing some sources]( to backup the answer. You should cite some sources, would be quote from text of Ramayana.